# Text Search with exact string in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

My mongo document looks like below:

I need to search with DEC19061936uuuu.
I tried with

```
db.getCollection('FSL_EventStatusService').find( { $text: { $search: "DEC19061936uuuu" } } )
```

```
db.getCollection('FSL_EventStatusService').find( { $text: { $search: "\"DEC19061936uuuu\""  } } )
```

Nothing gives the result. Every time I am getting fetched 0 records.
How to search with partial text search? which will be same as sql's like operator.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3d802666556e3f88f16f65"),
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2020-08-19T19:40:20.886Z"),
    "Level" : "Information",
    "MessageTemplate" : "{Type}{FeatureTeamName}{ApplicationName}{MethodName}{EntityType}{EntityValue}{ElapsedMilliseconds}{Exception}{Hostname}{CorrelationId}{Message}{CustomException}{AdditionalInfo}{Timestamp}",
    "RenderedMessage" : "\"input\"\"FSL\"\"EventStatusService\"\"RabbitMQServices.PushToRMQ\"\"ASN\"\"DEC19061936uuuu\"0null\"W1022MQ8Y2\"\"229fe501-8fb4-4b64-b7f2-1ec3a41eda34\"\"[\\\"Pushed message {\\\\\"KeyName\\\\\":\\\\\"ASN\\\\\",\\\\\"KeyValue\\\\\":[\\\\\"DEC19061936uuuu\\\\\"],\\\\\"DataSource\\\\\":\\\\\"OFS\\\\\",\\\\\"Region\\\\\":\\\\\"EMEA\\\\\",\\\\\"EventType\\\\\":\\\\\"2TRELIEF\\\\\",\\\\\"MessageType\\\\\":\\\\\"2TRELIEF\\\\\",\\\\\"EventTimestamp\\\\\":\\\\\"2020-08-19T14:40:08.321-05:00\\\\\",\\\\\"Attributes\\\\\":[{\\\\\"AttributeName\\\\\":\\\\\"REQUEST_NUM\\\\\",\\\\\"AttributeValue\\\\\":null},{\\\\\"AttributeName\\\\\":\\\\\"TraceID\\\\\",\\\\\"AttributeValue\\\\\":\\\\\"229fe501-8fb4-4b64-b7f2-1ec3a41eda34\\\\\"}]} successfully to Q.FSL.ORCHESTRATION.FSL\\\"]\"nullnull08/19/2020 19:36:03",
    "Properties" : {
        "Type" : "input",
        "FeatureTeamName" : "FSL",
        "ApplicationName" : "EventStatusService",
        "MethodName" : "RabbitMQServices.PushToRMQ",
        "EntityType" : "ASN",
        "EntityValue" : "DEC19061936uuuu",
        "ElapsedMilliseconds" : 0,
        "Exception" : null,
        "Hostname" : "W1022MQ8Y2",
        "CorrelationId" : "229fe501-8fb4-4b64-b7f2-1ec3a41eda34",
        "Message" : "[\"Pushed message {\\\"KeyName\\\":\\\"ASN\\\",\\\"KeyValue\\\":[\\\"DEC19061936uuuu\\\"],\\\"DataSource\\\":\\\"OFS\\\",\\\"Region\\\":\\\"EMEA\\\",\\\"EventType\\\":\\\"2TRELIEF\\\",\\\"MessageType\\\":\\\"2TRELIEF\\\",\\\"EventTimestamp\\\":\\\"2020-08-19T14:40:08.321-05:00\\\",\\\"Attributes\\\":[{\\\"AttributeName\\\":\\\"REQUEST_NUM\\\",\\\"AttributeValue\\\":null},{\\\"AttributeName\\\":\\\"TraceID\\\",\\\"AttributeValue\\\":\\\"229fe501-8fb4-4b64-b7f2-1ec3a41eda34\\\"}]} successfully to Q.FSL.ORCHESTRATION.FSL\"]",
        "CustomException" : null,
        "AdditionalInfo" : null,
        "Timestamp" : "2020-08-19T19:36:03.3161314Z"
    },
    "UtcTimestamp" : "2020-08-19 19:40:20Z"
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace all punctuation in the field being searched with spaces?

Comment: Do you have text index on `RenderMessage` field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **Text Index** on your collection to find the results as you are doing **Text Search**. It should be similar as follows.

```
db.getCollection('FSL_EventStatusService').createIndex(
{"RenderedMessage":"text",
"Properties.EntityValue":"text"}
)
```

Now fire your queries. [More](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

But if you intend to do partial search on specific fields, then you don't need to create **Text Index**. You can fire queries as usual and see the results using **Regular Expression**. [More](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
db.getCollection('FSL_EventStatusService').find({'RenderedMessage': /DEC19061936/  } )

db.getCollection('FSL_EventStatusService').find({'Properties.EntityValue': {    $regex: 'DEC19061936'   }  } )
```